# Border with inverted rectangular corners

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

How do I create a non-rectangular border like in this image?

[image: Non-rectangular Corner]

Current Code: http://jsfiddle.net/bqjr5wep/

```
div {
    background:#1c1c1c;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}

div:before, div:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    position:absolute;
}

div:after {
    left:14px;
    top:14px;
    right:14px;
    bottom:14px;
}
```

Comment: Is your background a solid color or a gradient/image?

Comment: Solid Color or Image. Depending

Comment: A solid color is sort of easy to achieve. Image background might be tough and need SVG.

Comment: I feel that the CSS tag would also be more apt/useful for this question than HTML5 but I seem to have missed this when I edited the first time. Would you mind me editing it again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sample 1: Transparent background for shape with non-solid page background**

Here is an approach which supports non-solid background for the page (gradient or image), transparent background for the shape and also is scalable. The downside probably is the fact that it requires more than one element.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
.shape-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.shape:after,
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.shape:after {
  top: -4px;
  left: 10px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
}
.shape:before {
  top: 10px;
  left: -4px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
}
.shape-inner:before,
.shape-inner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.shape-inner:before {
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}
.shape-inner:after {
  bottom: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  border-width: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}
/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="shape-inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Sample 2: Solid color (non-transparent) background for shape**

If the shape needs to have a different background compared to the page background and the shape's background is a solid color then the same approach with a small modification can be used. Sample is provided below:

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
.shape-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: steelblue;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.shape:after,
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: steelblue;  
  border: 2px solid white;
  z-index: -1;
}
.shape:after {
  top: -4px;
  left: 10px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
}
.shape:before {
  top: 10px;
  left: -4px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
}
.shape-inner:before,
.shape-inner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.shape-inner:before {
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}
.shape-inner:after {
  bottom: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  border-width: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}
/* Just for demo */
body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="shape-inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Sample 3: Gradient/Image background for shape**

You can also add an image (or) gradient different from the page background to the shape's background and it would look like in the below snippet. It cannot follow the outer border of the shape exactly.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
}
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
.shape-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600);
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -4px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
}
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 10px;
  left: -4px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
}
.shape-inner:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}
.shape-inner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  bottom: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="shape-inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Sample 4: Semi-transparent background for shape**

This is the trickiest of the lot but can still be achieved by doing some minor modifications to the snippet. The idea for this was picked from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746860/how-to-handle-double-opacity-of-two-overlapping-divs).

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
.shape-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.shape:after,
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  border: 2px solid white;
  z-index: -1;
}
.shape:after {
  top: -4px;
  left: 10px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(80, 80, 80) 5px, transparent 5px) no-repeat, linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(80, 80, 80) 4px, transparent 4px) no-repeat;
}
.shape:before {
  top: 10px;
  left: -4px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(80, 80, 80) 5px, transparent 5px) no-repeat, linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(80, 80, 80) 4px, transparent 4px) no-repeat;
}
.shape-inner:before,
.shape-inner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.shape-inner:before {
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}
.shape-inner:after {
  bottom: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  border-width: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}
/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text/);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="shape-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty awesome Harry, thanks for your response. Can you elaborate whats the upside in doing this with pure css instead of an SVG border-image? Being able to choose whichever color and size you want without having to create a new SVG image? Not sure with which one to go.

Comment: @Snowball: Always happy to help mate. I don't think there is any great advantage over SVG for this case but I can't think of any major disadvantages either. Yes, there is an extra element but that's pretty negligible. The CSS approach used should work in IE8 whereas I think SVG doesn't.

Comment: @Snowball: Please mark any one of the answers as accepted. That is SO's way of marking a problem as solved :)

Answer (score 3):

I just created a simple SVG image and used the CSS border-image to create the desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/bqjr5wep/1/

```
div {
  width:80%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin:50px auto;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}

div:before, div:after {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top:10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

div:before {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 16px;
  -moz-border-image: url('http://imgh.us/border_1.svg') 16 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url('http://imgh.us/border_1.svg') 16 repeat;
  -o-border-image: url('http://imgh.us/border_1.svg') 16 repeat;
  border-image: url('http://imgh.us/border_1.svg') 16 repeat;
}

div:after {
  border:2px solid #FFF;
  left:14px;
  top:14px;
  right:14px;
  bottom:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/91sk6069/)

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}

.border-1{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.border-2{
    width: 391px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 3;
}

.top-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 2;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.bottom-1{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Hope it helps :) Happy Coding.

Comment: By the way this code doesn't contain svg. pure CSS. You can adjust the border sizes depends on your desired output.

Comment: @John: Sorry to nitpick but I think would work only with a solid color background.

Comment: Yes but if you have an image background you can still use this but with different CSS trick code :) Have fun. Glad to share some idea or solution.