# Overlaying Opacity of Divs cancellation

Tags: html, css, transparency, overlap

I'm trying to overlay two divs that have semi transparent backgrounds (same colour). How can i make sure that when they overlay that the opacity doesn't add to eachother?

Simply put, what I'm asking is how to make sure the colour is consistent trough the two divs even when overlapping. I've made a codepen to show where the issue is (where the green is darker)
    [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Taydog/pen/LRjmNL)

```
<style>
.div1{    
  background-color: rgba(20,101,20,0.5);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.div2{    
  background-color: rgba(20,101,20,0.5);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px
}
</style>

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: You could *not* use opacity and set the actual color value -> http://codepen.io/Unused/pen/ZpJoLW Not certain if that's possible because it depends on *why* you are using opacity in the color.

Comment: Use `#8AB28A` which looks same as the color-opacity combination that you use... as Scott says if you are using `opacity` it is not possible to prevent the 'issue' when they overlap.

Comment: You can check overlap of overlays by JS to decide on consistency. http://time2hack.com/2016/03/checking-overlap-between-elements.html

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746860/how-to-handle-double-opacity-of-two-overlapping-divs

Comment: I understand what you're saying @Scott and Kukkuz, however in the instance that I'm using this for there is a second div behind both of the current divs that has a background image, so solid colours cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

place `div1` and `div2` in a container and apply `opacity: 0.6` to it.

```css
.container{
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.div1{    
  background-color: rgba(20,101,20,1);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.div2{    
  background-color: rgba(20,101,20,1);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```