# Prevent two divs opacity from overlapping in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to make this shape with CSS

[image]

I've manage to get the shape I wanted by overlapping two divs but as you can see, when I lower the opacity of the elements, the overlapping area become visible.

Is there a way to prevent elements opacity from overlapping to give the impression that it is a solid "piece" ?

If not, how can I make this shape ?

Thanks !

Comment: `I've manage to get the shape` --> where ?

Comment: add the html and css you used to create this shape, a Fiddle would be great

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746860/how-to-handle-double-opacity-of-two-overlapping-divs Duplicate question, take a look at the answer provided here. Flagged.